# How to cleanup died jobs logs in storm?

Tags: apache-storm

I am trying to cleanup died storm jobs logs which stored in storm_log_path/workers-artifacts/

- my current approach is using cron job or log rotate to cleanup the directory but that is has a problem it is deleting logs even the job is running.
- what I am trying to do is using storm configuration to do this task as written in [storm-documentation](https://storm.apache.org/releases/1.2.3/SECURITY.html) the Log Cleanup section this options should cleanup the logs and will never delete the logs of running jobs but it didn't work.

I am using storm 1.2.3 and my storm.yaml

```yaml
logviewer.childopts: "-Xmx128m"
logviewer.cleanup.age.mins: 30
logviewer.max.sum.worker.logs.size.mb: 4096
logviewer.max.per.worker.logs.size.mb: 2048
```

I set the cleanup period to 30 minutes to test but never worked.
the log directory has folder for jobs per run there names are jobID-countingNumber-timestamp

```
5faaac990788a706cb972861-1-1607352884
5faaac990788a706cb972861-1-1607358710
5faaac990788a706cb972861-1-1607528615
5faaac990788a706cb972861-1-1607587744
5faaac990788a706cb972861-2-1607353512
5faaac990788a706cb972861-2-1607507502
5faaac990788a706cb972861-3-1607354786
```

How to allow the logviewer option to work or is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

In your `storm.yaml`, you need to add `logviewer.cleanup.interval.secs: <value>` for the logviewer cleaner service to work. Restart the logviewer service afterwards.

---

Your question made me curious so I have done some digging, first through the storm docs, then through our cluster's logs, then through the storm source code.

Turns out the logviewer cleanup service does not have a default value configured and is initialized with `null`. This is not mentioned in the docs, however, examining our own logviewer logs, this line popped to my eye:

`2020-12-10 13:34:42.129 o.a.s.d.l.u.LogCleaner main [WARN] The interval for log cleanup is not set. Skip starting log cleanup thread.`

Looking through the [default config file](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml) and the storm sources made it clear there is no default value configured and the process is initialized with `null` ([this file](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/4aa4797787675e604571a5f6a9f596d9f6b13d83/storm-webapp/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/daemon/logviewer/utils/LogCleaner.java), line 97), which actually does not start the cleanup service at all. Seems to me, that they forgot to mention that in their docs, so admins looking to configure the service would automatically set this.

After setting the value and restarting the logviewer, it immediately started cleaning the files, as I could see in the logs. So thanks for raising this question, it would have slipped my attention otherwise!

Comment: good catch I didn't notice this option and it works very fine

Comment: even they don't use it storm default.yaml https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/conf/defaults.yaml

Comment: Yepp. I think it would be nice to have it there. I will try to create a PR when I find the time.